# Can I get live wallpapers on iPhone5(iOS6)?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios, iphone

Does iOS 6 support Live wallpapers?
Are there any apps out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native iPhone iOS (un-jail broken) does not support Live wallpapers (as in Android). There are numerous apps available for jail broken iPhones in the Cydia app store. An example would be [vWallpaper](http://www.ijailbreak.com/cydia/vwallpaper-2-0-cydia-tweak/). Obviously you would have to jail break your iPhone to utilize a Live Wallpaper app.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. It might be possible if you jailbreak your device, but it's not a feature of stock iOS, and App Store rules prevent third party apps from changing the wallpaper or running in the background, which would be necessary for changing it on a schedule.